# add rows to pandas multindex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to balance some production flows of some countries which are stored in a pandas dataframe with multindex.

a simplified example of my problem could be something like this

```
dict_df1={2016: {('country A', 'peanuts', 'supply'): 3.0,
        ('country A', 'peanuts', 'demand'): 2.0,
        ('country A', 'olives', 'supply'): 1.0,
        ('country A', 'olives', 'demand'): 0.5,
        ('Country B', 'peanuts', 'supply'): 3.0,
        ('Country B', 'peanuts', 'demand'): 2.0,
        ('Country B', 'olives', 'supply'): 1.0,
        ('Country B', 'olives', 'demand'): 0.5},
 2017: {('country A', 'peanuts', 'supply'): 4,
       ('country A', 'peanuts', 'demand'): 3,
       ('country A', 'olives', 'supply'): 2,
       ('country A', 'olives', 'demand'): 2,
       ('Country B', 'peanuts', 'supply'): 4,
       ('Country B', 'peanuts', 'demand'): 3,
       ('Country B', 'olives', 'supply'): 2,
       ('Country B', 'olives', 'demand'): 2}}

pd.DataFrame(dict_df1)
```

[image]

I would like to add some rows in the 3rd level, with the difference between supply and demand. The result should be something like this:

[image]

I tried doing

```
s=df1.loc[(slice(None),slice(None),'supply'),:]
s.index=s.index.droplevel('category')

d=df1.loc[(slice(None),slice(None),'demand'),:]
d.index=d.index.droplevel('category')

b=s-d

df1.loc[(slice(None),slice(None),'difference'),:]=b
```

but I get a keyerror message. I think I need to somehow declare the new entries in the multiindex before assign any value, but I do not know how to do it. The real dataset has many countries, years and even more levels in the multiindex, so I am looking for a generalizable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `groupby` `diff` create the df you want to append , then we using `concat`

```
conbinedf=df.groupby(level=[0,1]).diff().dropna().reset_index(level=2).assign(level_2='diff').set_index('level_2',append=True)
yourdf=pd.concat([df,conbinedf]).sort_index(level=[0,1])
yourdf
Out[287]: 
                          2016  2017
Country B olives  demand   0.5   2.0
                  diff     0.5   0.0
                  supply   1.0   2.0
          peanuts demand   2.0   3.0
                  diff     1.0   1.0
                  supply   3.0   4.0
country A olives  demand   0.5   2.0
                  diff     0.5   0.0
                  supply   1.0   2.0
          peanuts demand   2.0   3.0
                  diff     1.0   1.0
                  supply   3.0   4.0
```

Comment: for some reason, I can't figure out why my df turns out to be empty when I apply df.groupby(level=[0,1]).diff()  my df is of similar structure two levels

Comment: @JaySabir not sure why, maybe you can post a question ?

Comment: It turned out to be string datatype in one rows. Anyways how can I sort the df based on 'diff' row and a specific column - without unstacking? can you point me in the direction?